# How do you add a button to the "navigation bar" in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-15

By default, in IntelliJ, the main toolbar is hidden. When it is hidden, there are essential buttons that are shown in the navigation bar. I don't need the full toolbar, but it would be nice to be able to add a single button to the navigation bar.

How do you add a button to the navigation bar?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can customize any menu or toolbar in IDEA in settings by going to:

> Settings-> Appearance and Behavior -> Menus and Toolbars

[image]

The item you are looking for is called

> Navigation Bar Toolbar

[image]